# Installed KDE Plasma and then removed it and now my computer is stuck in Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS tty1 cli

Tags: boot, networking, apt, kubuntu, kde

So earlier today I decided to install kde plasma on my computer which had ubuntu 18.04.3. I followed this guide to install it that told me to get tasksel, sddm, and kubuntu. Once I got all of that and had plasma set up, I decided I didn't like it that much so I removed kubuntu. When I did that and rebooted my computer it got stuck in 18.04.3 tty1 command line interface. I looked up as many solutions as I could and most of them suggest reinstall ubuntu desktop but the problem is that I can't even run sudo apt-get install anymore because it says "unable to fetch archives". I think the reason for this is that it is not connected to the internet, but I can't even use ifconfig to connect to the internet. After that, I tried to reinstall ubuntu using a bootable usb. However, even that would not work even when I tried to the "install ubuntu (safe graphics)" option with nomodeset. When I would try that it would just give me a black screen even though safe graphics is enabled. I would appreciate any help because I am totally lost.

EDIT: the reason I can't use ifconfig is because when i try to run it, i says "command 'ifconfig' not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt install net-tools" The same goes for vim editor or emacs

Comment: Please make a backup of everything in ~/ from your original configuration (probably _/dev/sda_) to another drive after booting from an Ubuntu LiveUSB, then verify the backup. Then, make another backup and verify it. You may need to reinstall from scratch, and losing your data would likely be painful.

Comment: "I followed this guide" but there's no link: I'd like to read that "guide" to see what precautions the reader was advised to take before actually doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Important packages are installed on the installation LiveUSB flash drive, so use two LiveUSB Ubuntu installer flash drives; one to boot from, and one to mount to access the packages you need. Create a second LiveUSB with the same version of Ubuntu you were using to install.

Boot from one of the LiveUSBs.

Mount the other LiveUSB (probably */dev/sdb)*  at a path (*/tmp/mnt* will work) with

`mkdir /tmp/mnt && sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /tmp/mnt`

Then, edit **/etc/apt/sources.list** to only contain

> deb file:///tmp/mnt/ main universe

Do `sudo apt-get update` then you can reinstall Gnome with `apt install meta-gnome3`.